# Наследование в языке стилей css

Tags: css

Каким образом реализовать наследование двух стилей в css?

Пример. Есть определение для класса

```
.text {
   border: 1px solid black;
}

.custom-text {
   padding: 15px
}
```

Есть ли способ задать стиль, который будет обладать каждым из этих свойств?

Comment: Может, Вам хотя бы азы изучить самостоятельно? htmlacademy.ru, например. А то вопросы из серии "Как вывести hello, world"

Comment: @humster_spb говорят, что такое css не поддерживает (=. Видимо, это не hello world?

Comment: В многочисленных расширениях css есть миксины, но в самом css такого нет

Comment: а зачем, если можно элементу указать сразу два класса и не дублировать css код?

Comment: @Grundy меня опередил: указываете элементу class="text custom-text", и он получает оба этих свойства. Это даже проще, чем hello world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, css такое не поддерживает.